# Edit event does not fire at the right time

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We have an app with nested grids which contain popup editors.

I've also played with a sample from Kendo which has nested grids with inline editing, and in both cases, when the details view is hidden to start with, the edit event fires when I click the 'expand', but it does not fire when we click 'edit'.

We want to disable radio buttons based on data in the parent object, but, the template gets build by the grid one on load ( which is sensible ), and the window gets constructed when needed, so even if we add our own click event to the button, it fires BEFORE the window exists, so it fails. We need to run javascript AFTER the edit window is visible.

This does not appear to be possible, and every answer we see, references the 'edit' event. Is it just broken in the current release? Or does it just not work for nested grids?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: If I posted the code, it would not help at all.  I did exactly what I've said.  In the .cshtml I do something like

.Events(e => e.Edit("alert('edit')")

and then when I use the expand button for the details view, the message  appears ( so the code works to hook it up ), and when I click 'Edit', it does not appear.  There's only one line of code to show, and it definitely hooks up the event to fire at the wrong time, and not when it's needed.

The other thing I did, succeeded in adding an 'onclick' to the edit button, but it fires before the page is in the DOM.